# No Such MethodError

Tags: android, java-native-interface, nosuchmethoderror

How do I understand this error ?

```
    05-13 11:07:39.699: E/AndroidRuntime(3878): Process: com.example.demo_app, PID: 3878
    05-13 11:07:39.699: E/AndroidRuntime(3878): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    no static or non-static method
    "Lcom/example/DEMO;.demoMode(ZZZLjava/lang/String;ZZ)Lcom/example/DEMOError;"
```

This code is written in a JNI typeof app

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html

Comment: listen, i knew that when i got the error, that the method doesnt exist, but what do the other symbols mean? how do i find the error in my code ?

Comment: This may help http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0286.html

Comment: I would help greatly if you can paste the method-call and the method-signature.

Comment: Have you verified with `javap` that the signature you're trying to use is correct?

Comment: As always with JNI, don't try to figure out the method signatures yourself. Use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Comment: The first part of your signature is wrong: the signature just specifies arguments and return type, but your seem to be including `Lcom/example/DEMO;.demoMode` for the class and method name, which are separate arguments to `GetStaticMethodID`, e.g. `id = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, helloWorldClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");`. Maybe I’m wrong, posting your call would make matters clearer.